# Using a Decorator, (rails) Could not infer a decorator for ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, decorator

I'm having trouble using a decorator. I've never used one before and I've been trying to use one with regards to something that I've been doing for breaking up some emails.

However because I've never used one before, I've been having trouble even doing very simple things with my decorator and I'm thinking there is some form of setup issue with it. I do know that everything outside of my little feature (aka the `gemfile` and such) are all up to date and proper.

The error I am getting is simply,

> Could not infer a decorator for ActiveRecord::Base.

Now I have a controller that is almost empty, but inside it, I have the active record portion saved like so.

```
class Admin::ReceivedEmailsController < Admin::ApplicationController
```

With my view being titled,

```
_receive_email.html.haml
```

All I am doing in my view as of right now is so:

```
  %td= received_email.decorate
```

My decorator

```
class Admin::ReceivedEmailsDecorator < Admin::ApplicationDecorator

def received_email
 if can? :update, @customer
   received_email.content
 else
   "You need to have the correct admin access to view the email"
 end
end
```

I feel like this would have to be such an elementary thing for me to be missing, but I'm not sure what it is. Would anybody have any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

After much further research, reverse engineering further decorators and reading more documentation. I learned that a model or a helper is needed for a decorator to be properly used.  Which due to my partial I did not have one specific model or helper to use.