# How to call decorate method when I want to call it from another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, draper

In user's home page I want to show the user's `phrases`.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if user_signed_in?
      @phrases = current_user.phrases.decorate
    end
  end
end
```

But this fails by `Could not infer a decorator`. I understand the error happens because only in proper controller I can use the `decorate` method.
I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877328/using-a-decorator-rails-could-not-infer-a-decorator-for-activerecordbase), but I may misunderstand it.

So if I want to use `decorate` method in situation like this, what is a good way to solve it?

Comment: I suppose what `current_user.phrases` return an array, do you have decorator for array? maybe you should use decorator on the instance of `phrase` in the related views?

Comment: I see, thanks! But there is still `Could not infer a decorator for ActiveRecord::Base.` error, when I call `phrase.decorate` in view.

Comment: Ops, sorry! I forgot to restart rails server. After restart it works fine!